# HTML CSS table with padding and borders

Tags: html, css

Trying to get `borders` on `table-rows`. If the table has `border-collapse` the borders apply but then the table looses the applied padding.

How to get the `red-borders` on the green table without loosing its padding? http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/

```
<style>
table {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
table.two {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color:orange;
}
table tr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
            <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
            <td>Amet sit ipsum</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="two">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
            <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
            <td>Amet sit ipsum</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want bottom border for table or cell?

Comment: @Kiran `border-bottom` for every table row so every  `<tr>` should habe a bottom border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/15/)**

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: green;
}
table.two {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color:orange;
}
table tr {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @caramba: note that retype table row to `display: block` isn't a good idea at all instead of this case where it seems it works.

Comment: @caramba: update: the solution above works just because in `TH`s is the same text. See what happens when you change the text in there - http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/18/. With `display: block` table lost the table's behaviour.

Comment: @panther thank you so much for your effort! but I can still stick with this solution cause if I have `<th>` they will have a given width... http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/20/

Comment: @caramba: no problem. When you think you have the correct solution, don't worry. Just remember that people can resize browser font, set bigger font as a default one in their browser, and setting width isn't solution. You just lost the table'e behaviour, with this access you can you set of divs. You what you want, I tried to show you it isn't the right way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add left padding to `th`s and right padding to `td`s into the second `table`.

```
table.two th {padding-left: 20px;}
table.two td {padding-right: 20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/3/

There is no way how to put color to rows when table isn't collapsed, because there are vertical spaces between cells to (so to row border would be discontinuous).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It kinda does the trick. Just sometimes I have tables without `<th>` which would brake then. Thats why it would be awesome to apply padding to the most outer (table) element..

Comment: @caramba: `td:first-child` is the first td in each row (the same as `th` in your example here). The last one is `td:last-child`, or with support in older browsers you can create selector like `td + td + td + td` for table with four `TD`s in a row. See, http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/17/

Answer (score 0):

I've made the tables exactly as you had before, but with a border on the bottom for every `<tr>` element.

```css
table {
    background-color: green;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

table.one tr th{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

table.one tr td{
    padding-right: 20px;   
}

table.two {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color:orange;
}
table tr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class="one">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
   <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
   <td>Amet sit ipsum</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table class="two">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
   <td>Dolor sit amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
   <td>Amet sit ipsum</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r11xa2un/16/